# Validating array of relative arrays(maps) with Respect/Validation?

Tags: php, validation, http, respect-validation

I'm trying to validate to following json:

```
{
    "variants": [
        {
            "variant_code": "1",
            "price": 12,
            "discount": 12,
            "height": 1,
            "longitude": 1,
            "width": 1,
            "weight": 1,
            "package_height": 1,
            "package_longitude": 1,
            "package_width": 1,
            "package_weight": 11,
            "stock": 1
        },
        {
            "variant_code": "2",
            "price": 12,
            "discount": 12,
            "height": 1,
            "longitude": 1,
            "width": 1,
            "weight": 1,
            "package_height": 1,
            "package_longitude": 1,
            "package_width": 1,
            "package_weight": 11,
            "stock": 1
        },
        {
            "variant_code": "3",
            "price": 12,
            "discount": 12,
            "height": 1,
            "longitude": 1,
            "width": 1,
            "weight": 1,
            "package_height": 1,
            "package_longitude": 1,
            "package_width": 1,
            "package_weight": 11,
            "stock": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't find a way to validate it, I've tried to following methods:

```
$this->validator->validate(
            $request, [
                        "variants" => v::arrayVal()->each(
                            v::key("variant_code", v::stringVal()->notEmpty()->length(1, 100)),
                            v::key("stock", v::intVal()->notOptional()),
                            v::key("price", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                            v::key("discount", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                            v::key("weight", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                            v::key("width", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                            v::key("height", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                            v::key("longitude", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                            v::key("package_weight", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                            v::key("package_width", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                            v::key("package_longitude", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                            v::key("package_height", v::numericVal()->notEmpty())
                        )
                    ]
        );
```

But it just validates the first key "variant_code" of each relative array.
I also tried this:

```
$this->validator->validate(
            $request, [
                        "variants" => v::arrayVal()->each(
                            v::keySet(
                                v::key("variant_code", v::stringVal()->notEmpty()->length(1, 100)),
                                v::key("stock", v::intVal()->notOptional()),
                                v::key("price", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                                v::key("discount", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                                v::key("weight", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                                v::key("width", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                                v::key("height", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                                v::key("longitude", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                                v::key("package_weight", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                                v::key("package_width", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                                v::key("package_longitude", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
                                v::key("package_height", v::numericVal()->notEmpty())
                            )
                        )
                    ]
        );
```

But it throws the following error:

```
{
        "variants": {
            "variants": "Must have keys `{ \"variant_code\", \"stock\", \"price\", \"discount\", ... }`"
        }
```

I've also tryied many other ways unsuccessfully.
I'm working with Respect/Validation version 2.0 and PHP version 7.4.
Anyone knows how to do it, with respect/validation?(I already know how to do it manually). Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Are you using an additional library/middleware for this validation, since I see `$this->validator->validate`?

Comment: I'm just initializing the validator as a global variable on the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `product_image_id` key that is required by your rules but it's not present in the data you're trying to validate.

What I tried:

```php
$string = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "./data.json");
$json = json_decode($string, true);

function validate($data) {
    v::arrayVal()->each(
        v::keySet(
            v::key("variant_code", v::stringVal()->notEmpty()->length(1, 100)),
            v::key("product_image_id", v::optional(v::intVal())), // This key is missing in the data.json file
            v::key("stock", v::intVal()->notOptional()),
            v::key("price", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
            v::key("discount", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
            v::key("weight", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
            v::key("width", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
            v::key("height", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
            v::key("longitude", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
            v::key("package_weight", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
            v::key("package_width", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
            v::key("package_longitude", v::numericVal()->notEmpty()),
            v::key("package_height", v::numericVal()->notEmpty())
        )
    )->assert($data);
}

try {
    /*
    $array = [
        [
            "variant_code" => "qwerty"
        ]
    ];
    $result = validate($array);
    */

    validate($json["variants"]);
    echo ("Validation ok");
} catch(NestedValidationException $exception) {
    echo($exception->getFullMessage());
    echo ("Validation error");
}
```

`data.json` file:

```json
{
    "variants": [
        {
            "variant_code": "1",
            "price": 12,
            "discount": 12,
            "height": 1,
            "longitude": 1,
            "width": 1,
            "weight": 1,
            "package_height": 1,
            "package_longitude": 1,
            "package_width": 1,
            "package_weight": 11,
            "stock": 1
        },
        {
            "variant_code": "2",
            "price": 12,
            "discount": 12,
            "height": 1,
            "longitude": 1,
            "width": 1,
            "weight": 1,
            "package_height": 1,
            "package_longitude": 1,
            "package_width": 1,
            "package_weight": 11,
            "stock": 1
        },
        {
            "variant_code": "3",
            "price": 12,
            "discount": 12,
            "height": 1,
            "longitude": 1,
            "width": 1,
            "weight": 1,
            "package_height": 1,
            "package_longitude": 1,
            "package_width": 1,
            "package_weight": 11,
            "stock": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

You can check my complete code [here](https://github.com/DavidePastore/stackoverflow67216544).

Comment: I made a mistake copy/pasting, even if I remove the key it doesn't work, check that the error is saying the more keys are missing, not just product_image_id. Are you sure that your code work?

Comment: @FrancescArolas, yes, I think this is the expected behavior, since a `KeySet` is a group of rules. You can check [its implementation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/2.0.17/library/Rules/KeySet.php) and the [related exception](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/blob/2.0.17/library/Exceptions/KeySetException.php).